# Database.insert issue

Tags: apex

I have this piece of code,where i am trying to insert a record(which throws me duplicate issue).But i am trying to insert it using database.insert

```
EntitySubscription e = [select id from EntitySubscription where ParentId = 'a0CM0000005hyYAMAY' and SubscriberId= '005M0000005BqhVIAS'];
//e exists
EntitySubscription a = new EntitySubscription(ParentId = 'a0CM0000005hyYAMAY',SubscriberId= '005M0000005BqhVIAS');
List<EntitySubscription> collaborationBetMembers = new List<EntitySubscription>();
collaborationBetMembers.add(a);
Database.Saveresult[] saveResult; 
saveResult = Database.insert(collaborationBetMembers);
system.debug(saveresult);
```

Now my issue is above code throws an exception
but when i specify false parameter explicityly in

```
saveResult = Database.insert(collaborationBetMembers,false);
```

It doesnt throw exception.
which is confusing because this documentation shows,its false my default..so my assumption is you dont need to write it explicitly.any idea why
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Exception i get is below

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: duplicates value on record with id: : []:
```

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: i updated above with exception :)

Comment: Database.insert should always take 2 parameters as per this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Database_static_methods.htm . I cant find the method that takes only one parameter. Nor can i find anything specifying any default value.

Comment: No where in document says the parameter is false by default

Comment: I agree with above, the only thin I could find on default values for AllOrNone is here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_allornoneheader.htm.  This is for the API though and I don't think applies here.  You have to set both parameters for the method.

Comment: in the link which i have specified above.if you go to left navigation and databasenamespace->dmloptionsclass->dmloptions properties->optallornone.It says If optAllOrNone is set to true, all changes are rolled back if any record causes errors. The default for this property is false and successfully processed records are committed while records with errors aren't.

Comment: May be i am looking at wrong place.but this was what confused me

Answer (score 3):

This code does throw exception.
It is just handled and saved in SaveResult Object.
Quite similarly like try{} Catch(exception ex){} - here it also does throw exception but don't break session because you handle it.

Solution for you is to create method that will check SaveResult and look for error.

```
for(Database.SaveResult sr : saveResult){            
    if (!sr.isSuccess()) {
        /** Some tasks if Error found **/
    }
}
```

Comment: This is referred to as partial processing.  More details may be found here: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling